# How to move a ball over a line in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I'm trying to click a simple canvas application to demonstrate my presentation. It will be just when you click the button there will be a ball moving over the line from left to right at a constant speed. I'm just trying to demonstrate the streams of events.

Here's where I'm starting which is not much. 
http://jsfiddle.net/noppanit/z5VwL/1/

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>

<input type="button" onclick="clickToAddBall()" value="Click"/>



    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(10, 10);
context.lineTo(400, 10);
context.stroke();


function clickToAddBall() {
    // Do something
}

function gameLoop() {
    var loop = 400;
    setInterval(function() {
        loop = loop - 10;
        drawABall(loop);
    }, 200);
}
gameLoop();

function drawABall(positionX) {
      var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
      var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
      var radius = 5;

      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(positionX, 10, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      context.fillStyle = 'green';
      context.fill();
      context.lineWidth = 5;
      context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
      context.stroke();
}
```

Comment: What should happens when it reach the end of line?

Comment: It will just disappear.

Comment: You need some more work to do. **Hint:** 1) Add animation loop to make objects movable. 2) Create a simple circle(ball) using `arc()` method. 3) Listen to the click event, draw and increment `x` value of circle(ball) within animation loop.

Comment: This should get you started somewhat: http://jsfiddle.net/VzzJ6/

Comment: and a good tutorial that will teach you everything you need: http://billmill.org/static/canvastutorial/ball.html

Comment: all you need is a conditional + call to clearInterval() after you decrement loop and it's less than `x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Canvas Structure for begginers:

1) Animation Loop:

```
    // RequestAnimFrame: a browser API for getting smooth animations
window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame    || 
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||  
        function( callback ) {
            return window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 1000);
        };
})();
window.cancelRequestAnimFrame = (function() {
    return window.cancelAnimationFrame              ||
        window.webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame    ||
        window.mozCancelRequestAnimationFrame       ||
        window.oCancelRequestAnimationFrame         ||
        window.msCancelRequestAnimationFrame        ||
        clearTimeout
} )();
```

2) Create Ball

```
    ball = {
    x: canvas.width / 2 - 10,
    y: canvas.height / 2 ,
    r: 12,
    c: 'white',
    vx: 8,
    vy: 8,

    // function for drawing ball on canvas
    draw: function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = this.c;
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
        ctx.fill();
    }
```

3) Add EventListener to window for example, in handler we run animation:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas'),
var run = true;
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", btnClick, true);
function btnClick(e) {
    if(run){
                    ball.draw();
        animloop();
        run = false;
    }
}
```

4) Use Update function, to change x, y position of ball on every frame.

```
function Update() {
    // Move the ball
    ball.x += ball.vx;
    ball.y += ball.vy;
}
```

5) Function that draws everything, unlimeted loop:

```
function animloop() {
    init = requestAnimFrame(animloop);
    Update();
}
```

6) Ball will gone from canvas window. For it you need collision detection. If ball.x > some.value THEN ball.vx = 0; If you dont need vy, you can setup it to zero. Good Luck!